# How to move correctly block-search and minicart to panel wrapper? Magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1, layout, xml

[image: Example]
How to move correctly block-search and minicart to panel wrapper?

Comment: I tried to move `header wrapper` into `top.links` but it is not succeed. I can suggest instead of moving the `header wrapper` into `top.links`. you can remove `top.links` and include it as custom phtml into `header wrapper`.

Comment: have you gotten answer of this question?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to move them to **header panel**, below code can do your work

```
<move element="top.search" destination="header.panel" />
<move element="minicart" destination="header.panel" />
```

Place this code in your extended **default.xml** under Magento_Theme module

```
app\design\frontend\vendorname\themename\Magento_Theme\layout\default.xml
```

This way you can change position of other elements as well  by defining new destination to them.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
Magento_Theme\layout\default.xml
```

Move Element to **Header Panel** use below code

```
<move element="top.search" destination="header.panel" befor="-" />
<move element="minicart" destination="header.panel" before="-" />
```

You can use **"before" = "-"** to place your element at the very begin of the destination and **"after" = "-"** to place your element at the very end of the destination.

Comment: I have to sue this code but not working please go through my question  "https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/259837/magento2-top-header-section-change-layout?noredirect=1#comment366218_259837"