# How to Customize Magento 2 header layout with luma theme

Tags: magento2, template, css, luma-theme

I use Magento 2 with luma theme and trying to change the header layout but I don't know the best way to do that.

ie. I want the logo in div with some styles and the navigation in another div and so on.

How to achieve this?

Comment: have you extended your theme already ?

Comment: Yes I applied my custom theme and trying to change the layout

Comment: currently your logo coming in header content and menu in section-items, you want to add Div around logo and menu . right ?

Comment: Yes that's I want and I need to put the search box and cart icon in another div and need to give this div's some styles

Comment: please share a screenshot pointing the new locations for elements , because few changes can be done via .phtml and css and others can be done via xml

Answer (score 5):

**Customizing Header in extended LUMA Theme**

1. Adding a **<DIV />` around your logo and giving styles**:

   Edit `logo.phtml` and put a Div around the logo. Assign a class to the DIV and define styles to this class in your CSS files.

   ```
   app/design/frontend/vendorname/themename/Magento_Theme/templates/html/header/logo.phtml
   ```

   **Use `_extend.less`** for adding custom styles

   ```
   app/design/frontend/vendorname/themename/Magento_Theme/web/css/source/_extend.less
   ```
2. **Edit your search box** in your extended module, extend if not extended. Add a DIV around it and assign our class and define styles in `_extend.less`

   ```
   app/design/frontend/vendorname/themename/Magento_Search/templates/form.mini.phtml
   ```
3. The same method as above you can use for **Navigation** at the below path in `sections.phtml`

   ```
   app/design/frontend/vendorname/themename/Magento_Theme/templates/html/header/sections.phtml
   ```

I hope this will help you

If you need to **move element in top bar** then check my answer on this question [How to move correctly block-search and minicart to panel wrapper? Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/181691/how-to-move-correctly-block-search-and-minicart-to-panel-wrapper-magento-2)

Run **`upgrade/deploy/cache`** command to see the CSS changes if you are using `_extend.less` for custom styling

Comment: Thank you, I will try this solution and I will come back to you if I have a problem

Comment: sure, let me know if any problem

Comment: Please I need to put search box and cart icon and sign in link in one div,

Comment: did you try the another answers mentioned here https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/181691/how-to-move-correctly-block-search-and-minicart-to-panel-wrapper-magento-2  if yes then pass your site URL to check

Comment: SIGN IN coming in panel header DIV so with help of that answer you can move mini cart and search box to panel header  DIV.

Comment: I already moved it in the place I want using this codes in default.xml
`  <referenceBlock name="wish-list-link" remove="true" />
  <referenceBlock name="my-account-link" remove="true" />
  <referenceBlock name="register-link" remove="true" />
  <referenceBlock name="advanced-search-link" remove="true"/>
  <move element="authorization-link" destination="header-wrapper" after="register-link"/>`

Comment: please pass your site URL and paste the XML code in question itself , here in comment its not coming properly and I can't see minicart/topsearch moved to header panel

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62073/discussion-between-manoj-deswal-and-kareem-sultan).

Comment: My theme doesn't have templates folder what to do ?

Comment: you can create one if you don't have

Answer (score 4):

You can create your custom theme. Refer to [devdocs](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html)
and set parent theme to Blank.

You can move logo and navigation with move tag. Refer to [layout instructions](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-instructions.html).

You can add html class to a div through xml layout like this:

```
<container name="header.box" htmlClass="box-header" htmlTag="div" before="-">
            <container name="panel.wrapper.top" htmlClass="panel wrapper" htmlTag="div" before="-">
            </container>                    
</container>
```