# How to change the contents in the header of Magento 2

Tags: magento2, layout, header, page-layouts, header.panel

I have attached the screenshots images of my store and the model how it should appear. I have to change according to that. can anyone please help how to change or customize the header of the magento 2.[image]

I have to change the header in **1st image** to the header in the **2nd image**

[image]

Comment: Do some to create custom container into
app/design/frontend/Agtech/mapharma/Magento_Theme/layout

Answer (score 1):

Do some to create custom container into

> app/design/frontend/Agtech/mapharma/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml

Just Use Move to function for that design.

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/327731/57334 help me thanks @Rohan Hapani

Answer (score -1):

**Customizing Header in extended Your Current Theme**

You need to make changes in following files.

1 ) Adding **DIV around your logo and giving styles**

```
app/design/frontend/vendorname/themename/Magento_Theme/templates/html/header/logo.phtml
```

**Use _extend.less** for adding custom styles

```
app/design/frontend/vendorname/themename/Magento_Theme/web/css/source/_extend.less
```

2 ) **Edit you search box** in your extended module, extend if not extended . Add DIV around and assign our class and define styles in _extend.less

```
app/design/frontend/vendorname/themename/Magento_Search/templates/form.mini.phtml
```

3 ) Same above method you can use for **Navigation** at below path in sections.phtml

```
app/design/frontend/vendorname/themename/Magento_Theme/templates/html/header/sections.phtml
```

I hope this will help you, let me know if any issue

Run **upgrade/deploy/cache** commands to see the CSS changes if using _extend.less for custom styling

Thanks

Comment: You should have marked this question as duplicate instead of simply copying it! At least give credit to the original source. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/183266/how-to-customize-magento-2-header-layout-with-luma-theme