# How to move custom link right after logo in custom theme?

Tags: magento2.3.4, custom-theme, header.panel

I have created custom link under

app\design\frontend\Myrwd\mytheme\Magento_Theme\layout\default.xml

```
<!-- location added in header -->
<referenceBlock name="header.links">
<block class="Magento\Framework\view\Element\Html\Link" name="custom-link" before="-">
<arguments>
<argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true"> Custom Link </argument>
<argument name="path" xsi:type="string" translate="true"> customlink </argument>
</arguments>
</block>
</referenceBlock>
```

Now my custom link placed between customer link and minicart, how should place right after logo?

Workout :

In same path (app\design\frontend\Myrwd\mytheme\Magento_Theme\layout\default.xml)

I have added,

```
<move element="custom-link" destination="header-panel" after="logo" />
```

Its not working, how to solve the issue?

Comment: The header should be responsive by default if you had inherited the theme and header properly. Please post the code of your layout xml so we can check anything that you did wrong.

Comment: May i know which file you exactly need?

Comment: Can you pls join chat?

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117247/https-magento-stackexchange-com-questions-327731-how-to-add-responsive-alignmen

Comment: is bootstrap working properly?

Comment: Yes, bootstrap working

Comment: @fmsthird I have added custom link in header, i want move that custom link right after logo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace this below code inside your **default.xml** file :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="header.links">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\view\Element\Html\Link" name="custom-link" before="-">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true"> Custom Link </argument>
                    <argument name="path" xsi:type="string" translate="true"> customlink </argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
        <move element="custom-link" destination="header-wrapper" after="logo" />
    </body>
</page>
```

Clean cache and check it.

Comment: My logo under "panel header" and the custom link placed under "header content". FYI for UI customization i moved all the header content into panel header which means move all things to top header?

Comment: Then, just change destination and check it.

Comment: If I change with destination="panel-header" custom link hide.

Comment: You want to move custom link inside panel header. Right?

Comment: yes, right, because all my header links under here.

Comment: set destination="header.panel" and check it. Let me know if still not solved.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117283/discussion-between-zus-and-rohan-hapani).

Comment: can you pls see my updated post in chat section.

Comment: pls check it chat..

Comment: pls look chat...

Comment: New post : https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/328034/57334

Answer (score 1):

**Try it :-**

> You can create custom container in header :-

```
<referenceContainer name="header-wrapper">
     <container name="your-container-name" label="Header Top" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="your-header-top" after="logo">
     </container>
</referenceContainer>
```

> After Create container you can move your custom link in custom
> container :-

```
<move element="custom-link" destination="your-container-name" before="-" />
```

Comment: try this and let me know if not working.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this,**

```
<move element="custom-link" destination="header-wrapper" after="logo" />
```

Comment: My logo under "panel header" and the custom link placed under "header content". FYI for UI customization i moved all the header content into panel header which means move all things to top header?

Comment: please share your full code of the file

Comment: full code : https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117253/https-magento-stackexchange-com-questions-327731-how-to-move-custom-link-right

Answer (score 0):

you have a typo mistake in your `move` tag

```
<move element="custom-link" destination="header-panel" after="logo" />
```

the `destination` should be `header.panel`

```
<move element="custom-link" destination="header.panel" after="logo" />
```