# External css for specific cms block not cms page

Tags: css, custom-options, magento2.3.4

I have created custom theme which is inherit from blank theme, How to add external css for specific cms block in Custom theme?

Comment: You can't able to assign specific file for specific cms block. You need to manage it by parent class hierarchy.

Comment: Can you pls give me the suggestion, i just added inline css for cms block, how to handle in single css file?

Comment: You can manage from _extend.less file.

Comment: Okay, for eg. i have class "<div class="container">" all my cms block have the same name i mean "class="container" how to handle this situation?

Comment: I hope you understand my point.

Comment: You can add unique class with container class or manage it by parent class.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117368/discussion-between-zus-and-rohan-hapani).

Answer (score 0):

You can add it as HTML from admin panel:

```
<link href="http://test.com/media/examples/link-element-example.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: You mean inside the CMS block right, if supposed my css files under custom theme web/css then how to include into my CMS block

Comment: You can add class wrapper for each CMS block if you want to use CSS from your theme. For example content for cms-block-1: `<div class="cms-block-1">[content]</div>`. And global less file like **_theme.less** should have similar CSS rule `.cms-block-1 {color: red; border: green;}`

Comment: Instead of overwrite ( _theme.less ) i have created _extend.less file, shall i include inside the _extend.less file?

Comment: All new CSS rules you write in **_extend.less**

Comment: Finally done. add css inside _theme.less under app\design\frontend\Myrwd\mytheme\web\css\source\ _theme.less the css style will apply on CMS Block. I didn't call css path inside my cms block but the css applied.

Comment: Same where i can add my js?