# Magento2 top header section change layout

Tags: magento2, layout, search, toplinks

Currently in my site display this

[image]

I need search section move to top  as look wise below

[image]

If anyone idea reply me how to search section move in magento2

Comment: chek this ref: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/layout-practice.html

Comment: @RakeshDonga I have to check it and in my default.xml add move command"<move element="top.search" destination="panel.wrapper" after="-" />" but not working icon added but not show search inputbox

Comment: Please don't forget to clear cache after change in layout xml files

Comment: my code is right or not?